# JMS health check failed: javax.jms.JMSException: Cannot add a consumer to a connection that had not been registered: ID:b60b8dda5452-40739-1621954316

Tags: java, activemq-classic, spring-jms

We are trying to a setup bridge between [on-prem AMQ to AWS AMQ](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-activemq-in-a-hybrid-cloud-environment-with-amazon-mq/).

When we are trying to add a network connector in `activemq.xml`, we are able successfully able to setup a bridge between on-prem and AMQ.

```xml
<networkConnector name="AWS-MQ-Bridge"
       duplex="true"
       uri="static:(url)"
       userName="user"
       password="password"
       networkTTL="2"
       dynamicOnly="false">
       <dynamicallyIncludedDestinations>
          <topic physicalName=">"/>
          <queue physicalName=">"/>
       </dynamicallyIncludedDestinations>
    </networkConnector>
</networkConnectors>
```

Our existing applications who are connected with on-prem ActiveMQ, started throwing health-check WARNING
On-Prem applications are Spring Boot and health-check is done through Spring actuator

```
JMS health check failed
javax.jms.JMSException: Cannot add a consumer to a connection that had not been registered: ID:b60b8dda5452-40739-1621954316869-1:3211
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:54)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1403)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1436)
    at org.apache.activemq.AdvisoryConsumer.<init>(AdvisoryConsumer.java:51)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1495)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.start(ActiveMQConnection.java:527)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool.start(ConnectionPool.java:125)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnection.start(PooledConnection.java:95)
    at brave.jms.TracingConnection.start(TracingConnection.java:89)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jms.JmsHealthIndicator$MonitoredConnection.start(JmsHealthIndicator.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jms.JmsHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(JmsHealthIndicator.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:84)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:98)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:98)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaHealthCheckHandler.getHealthStatus(EurekaHealthCheckHandler.java:103)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaHealthCheckHandler.getStatus(EurekaHealthCheckHandler.java:99)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshInstanceInfo(DiscoveryClient.java:1388)
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:117)
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator$1.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:101)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add a consumer to a connection that had not been registered: ID:b60b8dda5452-40739-1621954316869-1:3211
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processAddConsumer(TransportConnection.java:689)
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ConsumerInfo.visit(ConsumerInfo.java:352)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:336)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:200)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onCommand(WireFormatNegotiator.java:125)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:301)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.SslTransport.doConsume(SslTransport.java:171)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:233)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:749)
```

This error disappears if we remove `networkConnector` configuration. Any pointer for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The bridge has been created between on-prem to AWS
Our on-prem client where getting connected to AWS broker with wrong crdentails
To solve this we set following properties

```
 updateClusterClients="false" rebalanceClusterClients="false"
```